# Remove string/script from all files (recursive)

Tags: sed

One of my websites has been hacked, all the index.html and index.php files have been infected with a certain Javascript. I would like to have a unix command to remove this script from all files.

Script is here: http://pastie.org/private/6osrvd5zhphe372gblrc6w

I am trying to figure this out with sed but no luck so far

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed -i 's/<script>.*<\/script>//' fileName
```

will remove the tag script and all its content.

This works if you only have one `<script>` tag.

If you haven't only one, extend it with `try` keyword in the following way

```
sed -i 's/<script>try.*<\/script>//' fileName
```

## Edit

If you want to do it on all files in a recursive way, you can use a `find` command like this:

```
find . -name "index.html" -print | xargs sed -i 's/<script>try.*<\/script>//' fileName
```

where `.` is the current directory

Comment: thanks, the zxc part is unique to the malware script. I tried this: sed -i 's/<script>*if(zxc)*<\/script>//' index.php but no luck what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Actually, I figured it out. sed -i 's/<script>try{document.body++}catch(dgsgsdg){zxc=12;ww=window;}if(zxc).*<\/script>//' index.php

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
find src/ -name "index.html" -print | xargs sed -i 's/<script>try{document.body++}catch(dgsgsdg){zxc=12;ww=window;}if(zxc).*<\/scri‌​pt>//
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -pi -e 's/<script>.*<\/script>//g' index.html
```